# SetAccessControl "unauthorized operation" even when run as administrator

Tags: c#, permissions

I am trying to take ownership and change the ACL of a file in C#, but even as an administrator I am getting the exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

The user running the program has the ability to take ownership and change permissions through Windows interface.

My code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\temp\mount\Windows\System32\Boot\en-US\winload.exe.mui";
FileSecurity fileSec = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

fileSec.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User); 
File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fileSec); //exception thrown here
```

I even added a check to make sure the current user is member of administrator group:

```
WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);

bool isAdmin = wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator); //returns true
```

Background information: I am creating a WinPE image and need to replace the winload.exe.mui file.

Also, the current permissions on this file only give full access to "Trusted Installer".

I am running on Windows 7

Comment: Nope.jpg  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Resource_Protection Not sure what APIs can be used to overcome this, but something says "win32" to me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by running `takeown` in a command shell using a `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Then I was able to set the access control without error.

Strange that `takeown` works but the equivalent .NET libraries don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `File.SetAccessControl()` in your new method in place of `FileStream.SetAccessControl()`. I'd be willing to bet it works, too. MSDN actually recommends this practice:

*"While the FileStream class and SetAccessControl can be used on an existing file, consider using the File.SetAccessControl method as it is easier to use."*

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setaccesscontrol.aspx[^]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setaccesscontrol.aspx)